# How to make equal sized flex items when the items may contain different sized images?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Setting `flex: 1 1 0` on flex items does not work as I would expect when the flex items can contain different sized images.

In the example below, the flex-item that contains the image becomes much wider than the other ones.

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <p>Hi</p>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/11/Episkopi_01-2017_img11_Kourion.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <p>there</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <p>dear</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <p>reader</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gzLwn7cu/

I could try using width instead of flex properties. Then the flex-items get correct width, but the image overflows.

```
.flex-item {
  width: 25%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gzLwn7cu/1/

It is not until I add properties on the image itself that I am able to solve the problem.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gzLwn7cu/1/

However, I want to force child elements to be contained in flex-items of equal size (along the primary axis) without any knowledge of what might be in there.

Is it possible to set some kind of flex property that achieves this?

Answer (score 0):

Flex-bases will be your answer. `flex-basis: 50%;`. Flex bases adds a starting point from where to calculate `flex: 1 1 0` 
See here https://jsfiddle.net/8ex91kn0/

The width on the image you have to have because by default the image will be the full width of itself. in order it would size itself to the containing box we need the `width: 100%;`